# WebService login

Tags: web-services, netbeans

I have a question for all of you who know how webservices work.

At the moment I have implemented a hangman game using JSF. My database has the following tables:

- Player
- Game
- Turn
- Word

I have entity classes for all these tables. also I have:

PlayerController, GameController, TurnController, etc and PlayerFacade, GameFacade and so on.

My current login is in the PlayerController and the PlayerFacade. what I need to do now is to create a webService for the login, the register of the players and the game.

How can I achieve this?

The first step is to create a PlayerFacadeREST, isn't it?

Which beans/classes should I use to make the login?

Comment: It would depend on the type of web service you want to use. If you will use JAX-WS web services, follow [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-ws-tutorials/). If you will use JAX-RS web services, follow [this another tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html). Remember that in the end, the consumer will just execute a method that is executed somewhere in the LAN/WAN/net, probably wait more for the response but all the logic in your other classes *should not* change.

Comment: This is not a JSF specific problem. Creating and calling a webservice is absolutely not different in JSF than in any other MVC framework. A webservice is completely independent from JSF. After all, you just use the same lines of Java code to invoke it in JSF as you would do in any other framework and even in a plain Java application with `main()` method.

Answer (score 0):

you could do the auth service using restful, like http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html or using soap as in http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbis.html

Comment: from where are you going to call the auth service? from a backing bean? or from javascript?

Comment: from where should I call it? I have nothing implemented yet... The login I have calls the PlayerController.login from an xhtml file... I suppose in a webservice this works different... this is what I want to  know, whats the correct way to do this :)

Comment: With a werservice you have to do 2 things. 1 create the service (lets say soap). 2 create a client to consume it (stubs) and this client must be called from your method `PlayerController.login`

Comment: @dak I assume `PlayController` is a backing bean as you are using jsf

Comment: @dak think about the Web service as a class that is implemented somewhere else except in your code. For example, if you have something like `Player player = new PlayerFacade().login(user, password);`, then the web service call must be inside `PlayerFacade#login` method. For the other layers in your app, the web service consumption must not be a problem.

Comment: Maybe this helps you to guide me.
1.create project Webserver1 2.create java class to transfer information
3.create restfull webservicesi from database 4. create entities from databse for "turn" and "game" 5.modify playerFacadeRest so it checks passwd/username and create new "game" 6. modify partida bean so it can use defalut id generation for "game" 7. add new named query to check user/password 8. test webserver, should return new game id

2nd: CREATE a new project called WEbClient1 (with servlet, restull java client)

Comment: I've received the instructions above from my teacher... my first impression is that it is completely different from what I have. I thought adding a web service to my application shouldnt be so difficult :S

Comment: @dak I suggest to first follow the JAX-RS tutorial posted in this answer and create your own JAX-RS web service and consume it from a Java console application. After accomplishing this, move onto something more complex like creating a web service using your entities but still having a Java console application as your web service client. Then, instead of having the console app as client, make your current web application being the client. Breaking the problem in smaller steps will be the best way to: 1) Learn about the involved technology 2) Learn how to do the things 3) Do it anywhere anytime.

Comment: I dont know if what I'm thinking is the right way so I'll ask: I'll have a client and a server side and the webService is going to connect each other. the client will contain some xhtml file with javascript code where i'll invoke the webservice. The webService will receive the parameters passed by the jscript and create the query for the server, right?

Comment: @dak yes, take a look at this http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-multitier/

Answer (score 0):

Here goes my solution after studying all the tutorials in the world:

I've created a restfull ws from my entity class Player... Inside goes this:

```
public Receiver login(@PathParam("name") String name, @PathParam("password") String password) {

        Receiver r = new Receiver();

        //TODO TRY/CATCH
        Query createNamedQuery = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Player.findByNameAndPassword");
        createNamedQuery.setParameter("name", name);
        createNamedQuery.setParameter("password", password);
        Player j = (Player) createNamedQuery.getSingleResult();
        if(j == null){
            r.setReturn(-1);
            return r;

        }

// DO ANYTHING WE WANT... I CREATE A NEW GAME IN MY CASE
        Game g = new Game();

        p.setIdPlayer(j);
        getEntityManager().persist(g);
        getEntityManager().flush();
        r.setReturn(p.getIdGame());
        return r;

    }
```